# Check for empty values in array

Tags: java

```
String arr[]={"",""};

if(arr!=null && arr.length >0){
  // the condition is becoming true

}
```

I need to check for empty values and return false

Comment: You need to return false if any of the values are empty or if all of them are?

Comment: Iterate throught the array and then check for empty string.

Answer (score 1):

An empty string is still a value. The array has 2 'slots' available, therefore, its length is '2'.

You can query the individual objects in these slots, for example with: `for (String elem : arr) { if (elem.isEmpty()) ..... ; }`

Answer (score 1):

You can stream the array, filter out elements that are not empty strings and get the count. Like,

```
boolean b = Arrays.stream(arr).filter(x -> !x.isEmpty()).count() != 0;
```

That will be `false` if the array is "empty" (and `true` otherwise).

Comment: for 2 d arrays?

Comment: @kanda Your question contains no 2 d arrays. What are you asking?

Comment: it can be used for 2d arrays also?

Comment: Not without nesting. 2d arrays are arrays of arrays, this answer is for arrays of strings.

Comment: If `arr` is a 2d array, then `boolean b = Arrays.stream(arr).flatMap(Arrays::stream).filter(x -> !x.isEmpty()).count() != 0;`

Answer (score 0):

```
String arr[] = ["", ""];

if(arr!=null && Array.length>0){
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i]==""){
       return false;
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String arr[]={"",""};
int flag = 0;
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i]!="") {
        flag = 1;
        break;
    }
}
if(flag==0){
    //your code
}
```